AWS CDK: Catch All Errors from Step Function
I am working on a Step Function in CDK that is mostly just a chain of Lambdas;
lambda_1
      .next(lambda_2)
      .next(lambda_3)
      .next(lambda_4)
      .next(lambda_5)

Whenever any of the Lambdas throws an error (handled or unhandled) I need to be able to log the error, which I intend to do in another Lambda as I need to perform some cleaning. Now, I can do this by triggering the Lambda from the Step-Function-Failed event, but for visibility I'd rather keep the logging as a step in the Step Function. I've reviewed the documentation, can't find a generic place that the addCatch method is available.
Is there any way to add a catch to a Step Function in CDK to catch errors thrown by all steps?

You can't set a "global" catch for all states directly, but you can achieve the same result by pointing all task states' catch handlers to the same fallback state.
This is easy in the CDK.  Your LambdaInvoke tasks have an addCatch method, which they inherit from TaskStateBase:
myTasks.forEach((task: tasks.TaskStateBase) => {
    task.addCatch(myFallbackState);
});


That is a good option, I'll give it a shot.

Can confirm that this worked, but did make the step function graph look a bit cluttered for my use case. Have gone with just handling events with a Lambda external to the step function.

What I sometimes do is create a sfn.Parallel block with one branch and add all the 'normal' step function states in there. Then I add a catch to the whole branch. Code-wise it looks a bit clumsy, but in the UI it's very clear what is happening.

Fedonev's answer to this question is the most appropriate way of achieving what I asked.
However, for my use case it ended up making the Step Function in question look a bit cluttered, and as such I went with handling the Succeeded and Failed events from the Step Function in a separate Lambda. In case someone is looking for how to achieve a similar thing, the below CDK Typescript code is what I used to create the Rule which would pass the details of the event to the Lambda in question.
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Stack } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { IEventBus, Rule } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-events';
import { LambdaFunction as target_LambdaFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-events-targets';
import { IStateMachine } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions';
import { IFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { Queue as sqs_Queue} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';
import { Duration } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { NagSuppressions } from "cdk-nag";


export class LogSFNExecutionRule extends Construct {
    constructor(
        scope: Stack,
        constructPrefix: string,
        triggering_sfn: IStateMachine,
        target_lambda: IFunction,
        event_bus: IEventBus,
    ) {
        super(scope, `${triggering_sfn.node.id}-log`);

        const rule = new Rule(
            this,
            `${constructPrefix}-${triggering_sfn.node.id}-log`,
            {
                eventBus: event_bus,
                eventPattern: {
                    "source": ["aws.states"],
                    "detailType": ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
                    "detail": {
                        "stateMachineArn": [triggering_sfn.stateMachineArn],
                        "status": ["SUCCEEDED", "FAILED"],
                    },
                },
            },
        );

        const queue = new sqs_Queue(
            this, `${constructPrefix}-${triggering_sfn.node.id}-log-queue`
        );
    
        rule.addTarget(
            new target_LambdaFunction(
                target_lambda,
                {
                    deadLetterQueue: queue, 
                    maxEventAge: Duration.minutes(30), 
                    retryAttempts: 2,
                },
            )
        );

        NagSuppressions.addResourceSuppressionsByPath(
            scope,
            queue.node.path,
            [
                {
                    id: "AwsSolutions-SQS3",
                    reason: "More research needed before implementing Dead-Letter Queue.",
                },
                {
                    id: "AwsSolutions-SQS4",
                    reason: "Ingest pipeline trigger is not sensitive, HTTPS not needed.",
                },
            ],
            true
        );
    }
};

